# Error while changing user password in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am getting error while changing password for user via UI. Unable to change the password. I am using Wso2 Identity server version 5.10.0

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
  - Error updating SCIM metadata in doPostUpdateCredentialByAdmin listener 
    org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
```

Can someone tell what might be causing this issue?

```
Error details stack trace: ERROR 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
   - Error updating SCIM metadata in doPostUpdateCredentialByAdmin listener 
     org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) 
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.changePassword(UserAdminStub.java:3678) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.changePassword(UserAdminClient.java:102) 
  at org.apache.jsp.user.change_002dpasswd_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(change_002dpasswd_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:195) 
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) 
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) 
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) 
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) 
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) 
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) 
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) 
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) 
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) 
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) 
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) 

  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) 
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49) 
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119) 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) 
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) 
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) 
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) 
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) 
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) 
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: What is the userstore that you use?

Comment: Userstore is a sharedDB. But this error also occurs for primary user store.

Comment: What did you use as the primary userstore (default ReadWrite LDAP shipped with the product or JDBC/Read-Write active directory/ Read-Only LDAP etc.)?

Comment: Have both. Primary userstore which is by default and also added JDBC connection for Shareddb.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error with the default LDAP primary userstore store in IS-5.10.0. However, the cause for the above error would be an userstore exception thrown when updating the last modified date https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-provisioning-scim2/blob/cc7e81d6aa63efdafaf3574b6e4d12f2fb56a899/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/scim2/common/listener/SCIMUserOperationListener.java#L135